# DelayedJob sometimes cannot load job class with a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, autoload

Sometimes I've got errors in delayed_job worker
`NameError: uninitialized constant Notifiers::MessageNotifierJob`
full backtrace https://gist.github.com/olegantonyan/eeca9d612f9a10864efe

`Notifiers::MessageNotifierJob` is defined in `app/jobs/notifiers/message_notifier_job.rb`

By sometimes I mean that this job may fail -> retry -> succeed. Same thing with another jobs which has a namespace. Jobs without namespace work just fine.

I tried to add `app/jobs/` to autoload paths explicitly without any luck
`config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'jobs', '**/') ]`

The job itself looks like this

```
module Notifiers
  class MessageNotifierJob < BaseNotifierJob
    def perform(from, to, text)
      # some code to send slack notification
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Delayed job or autoloader are not to blame.

A week before adding these new jobs (like `Notifiers::MessageNotifierJob`) I've increased number of delayed job workers (using `capistrano3-delayed-job` gem) from 1 to 4. But, capistrano3-delayed-job haven't killed old delayed job process, and only started new 4. So I ended up with 1 old job without any knowledge about my new job classes. Whenever this old process picked the job it failed. Then one of the new processes picked this job and succeeded.

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer. Ran into the same issue.